# Why KL-Divergence is coming out to be reversed?

Tags: bayesian, kullback-leibler

I am trying to assess the difference between my prior distribution and the posterior distribution by calculating the KL divergence metric.

I am using the following KL divergence formula -

*KL = np.sum(posterior * np.log(posterior/prior))*

The problem is that the KL divergence values that I am getting are conveying a reverse interpretation. As per literature, if the value of KL divergence is low then the two distributions are similar to each other and if high then different.

However, the distributions which I can clearly see are similar are showing a large KL value let's say 1.35 and the distributions which are clearly different are giving low KL value let's say 0.2.

Example  -

I have a sales volume contribution % values for prior and posterior which are numpy arrays and I am using those contribution % only to calculate KL divergence.

For plotting, I am using seaborn displot to plot density plots using these contribution % and visualizing both prior and posterior on the same chart so that I can relate the KL divergence metric with prior and posterior distributions.

Do I need to convert these contribution % values into some probability distribution since KL divergence accepts probabilities only? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: Can you add an example? It’s hard for us to tell what’s going wrong if we don’t know what you’re looking at.

Comment: Can you provide a worked example of what you're observing?